# Comparacion de una dato char en una Struct

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo comparar un dato char de una Struct con ' H ' o ' M ' para saber si el sexo entrado por teclado es mujer o hombre..?

Comment: Hola @Jonathan jesus Por favor lee  [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para publicar tu pregunta correctamente. Siempre trantá de poner el código de lo que tienes echo o aunque sea un pequeño pseudo-codigo para este caso ayudaría. Saludos!

Comment: Usa el operador `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Supongamos que tiene la struct (por ejemplo) definida de la siguiente forma:

```
struct Registro{ 
   char sexo;
};
```

Puedes acceder al atributo *sexo* usando el operador " . " .

Supongamos que necesito acceder al atributo de un solo struct

```
char sexo = miregistro.sexo;
```

Supongamos que tienes un array de N registros de la forma array_registros[N], puedes ingresar al sexo haciendo:`

```
char sexo = array_registros[i].sexo;
```

Y recorrerlo con un bucle (for - while - do while) segun te sea mas conveniente para el caso desarrollado.

Sobre como compararlos una forma facil es la siguiente:

```
char sexo = miregistro.sexo;
if(sexo == 'H')
{ //ejecuto alguna tarea
}
else if(sexo == 'M'){
//ejecuto algo
}
```

Espero que te sea util